# Make the default value 0 in the section appearance for show in section menus - (typo3)

Tags: typo3

I've created my own content elements and can't figure out how to give the show in section menus under appearance value of 0 so its not automatically toggled active.. Does anybody know how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by setting / overriding a default value by TCA override. Place the following line of code

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['sectionIndex']['config']['default'] = 0;
```

to the following file of your extension:

```
your_ext/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php
```

More information about extending the TCA --> [TYPO3 documentation "Extending the TCA"](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/ExtendingTca/StoringChanges/Index.html)

Comment: This way, you would change the default value for *all* content elements :-(
IMO, the better way would be using columnsOverrides (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/Types/Index.html?highlight=override#columnsoverrides)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend configuring this in `your_ext/Configuration/TsConfig/Page`:

```
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.common.elements.yourCE.tt_content_defValues {
    sectionIndex = 0
}
```

This has the advantage that

- it is configured only when the CE is constructed
- the editor has the possibility to change it if he/she wants to
- it is only effected on your CE

Comment: This will only take effect if the CE is created via New Contenelement Wizard, or not? A simple change of the records CType would not care about this configuration. The same, if CE is created in List module.